# PHP explode array, how can I identify the separator?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the code:

```
$arr=explode(", ",$this->maList);
```

maList returns the entered mails:

```
"test@test.com, test2@test2.com"
```

However, I want it to know whether I've used space after the comma or no space. Because if I enter this:

```
"test@test.com,test2@test2.com"
```

Then it becomes a single array element.

What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just going to put another answer up, for those cases where there are spaces in the strings that you wish to keep.  Mapping the trim function to the array items will remove any extra whitespace from the beginning or end, but not the middle.

```
$arr = explode(",", $this->maList);
$arr = array_map("trim", $arr);
```

This could be useful if you had:

```
"Test Name <test@test.com>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I thought of the answer as I was writing the question, pretty easy actually. Since I'm grabbing emails, so forget the white spaces, so I just cut it off while casting the array.

```
$arr=explode(",",str_replace(' ', '', $this->maList));
```

Comment: simply use `trim`, it's far less cumbersome than str_replace: `$arr=explode(",", trim($this->maList));`